# Pass managedObjectContext (Core data) to other classes, correctly done?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I used the default template provided by Apple with Core Data (managedObjectContext is in AppDelegate). At first I was including appdelegate.h in every classes I needed to use managedObjectContext, but I saw this was not the correct way to do it. Apple says it's better to only pass the context to other classes that need it and so on, so I ended up doing it that way. Thing is, it looks a bit "hackerish" the way I did it, and I'm wondering if there's a better option or my solution is correct.

My app is currently setup like that (here's a SS of my storyboard):
[image]

So my root window is a UITabBarController, and each tab is a UINavigationController that points to multiple UITableViewController/UIViewController.

Here is what I have in my Appdelegate to pass the managedObjectContext instance to 2 tabs:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UITabBarController *rootViewController;
    UINavigationController *navigationController;
    ItemsTableViewController *itemsTableViewController;

    // Get the root window (UITabBarController)
    rootViewController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;


    // Get the second item of the UITabBarController
    navigationController = [[rootViewController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1];

    // Get the first item of the UINavigationController (ItemsTableViewController)
    itemsTableViewController = [[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
    itemsTableViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;


    // Get the third item of the UITabBarController (again ItemsTableViewController)
    navigationController = [[rootViewController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:2];

    // Get the first item of the UINavigationController (ItemsTableViewController)
    itemsTableViewController = [[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];    
    itemsTableViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

    return YES;
}
```

Everything works well, but having to call multiple times objectAtIndex to get to the right ViewController looks meh...

Anyone as a better solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should look at using the `prepareForSegue:` method to pass your managedObjectContext to the other controllers.

Alternatively, you can subclass the tab bar controller and add the managed object context as a property, which you can then access from anywhere within your app provided the tab bar controller is also there.

Finally, if you are only ever going to use one context (i.e. no multi threads) you can always setup a `CoreDataHelper` class with a class method that returns your default context whenever you ask for it. To avoid importing the helper in every single class just add the helper to your precompiled header file (.pch) and let it also import the `<CoreData/CoreData.h>` framework.

If you want to see an example of how this is done, checkout MagicalRecord on github https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord

[EDIT]
Here's an example of how you would pass the context using the `prepareForSegue` method. Remember that this method is called when a segue is about to initiate and it gives you the opportunity to setup the view controller that is about to be pushed. This is where you could pass delegate references and assign values to other variables in your destination view controller:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSString *segueIdentifier = [segue identifier];
    if ([segueIdentifier isEqualToString:@"YourSegueIdentifier"]) // This can be defined via Interface Builder
    {
        MyCustomViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        vc.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    }
}
```

Comment: Huum, subclassing the UITabViewController looks interesting. And also I'll make sure to bookmark MagicalRecord, but since it is my first project Using Core Data, I would rather not use a framework to really get all the concepts :) Except if you tell me MagicalRecord is really a must :P

Comment: @allaire I would actually do exactly as you said and get familiar with CoreData first. Once you are comfortable and know what's going on, then MagicalRecord IS a must :)

Comment: I might add that the "most correct" way of passing the context would be via `prepareForSegue:`. By adding a property to the tab bar controller you are signing off on the fact that your app will always have a reference to the tab bar controller so should you decide to change that in the future, it will be a pain.

Comment: If you have a minute and could hook me up with a litle snippet of code about prepareForSegue:, that would be awesome! Thanks for all your support :) Or maybe it's the same code as I have, it would just make more sense to move it up there?

Comment: Thank you! oh and I've looked at MagicalRecord, and having a pretty good background with Active Record ORM, this helper looks awesome! Is there any limitions by using it? There's lack of docs, but the code looks clean so...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6779/discussion-between-allaire-and-rog)

Comment: I don't understand the solution with prepareForSegue... Should prepareForSegue be implemented on the different navigation controllers in the above picture? But those navigation controllers are not custom classes as far as I understand, they are just plain UINavigationControllers... So do you suggest subclassing UINavigationController and UITabBarController just to pass along the managedObjectContext?